# Could not connect to remote Server when calling Web API from MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

My Web Api throws error when I run it.It says

> Server Error in '/' Application

So,to fix it I have changed `Help/{action}/{apiId}` to `{Controller}/{action}/{apiId}` in RegisterArea method in HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs. Below is the method.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "HelpPage_Default",
        "Help/{action}/{apiId}",
        new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

    HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

Now,the issue is fixed,but when I run my web app,it gives me error saying couldnot connect to Remote server.Below is the line that calls api from web app.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Authenticate", model).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and in web api,

```
[Route("Authenticate")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateModel]
public AuthResponseServiceModel Authenticate(AuthRequestServiceModel sm)
{
    //code
}
```

completely not sure how my fix in api broke the connection between web app and web api.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Assuming you have enabled attribute routing, do you have [RoutePrefix("Account")] on top of your controller?

Comment: May be a very stupid doubt; did you try prefixing a "/" Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/Account/Authenticate", model)

Comment: Yes..I have tried ..but no luck..

Comment: The exact exception message says,"Resource not found"

Comment: Could you use fiddler or any other tool to inspect the request? I kinda feel there is something to do with the routing. You do have enabled attribute routing in web api config, is it? config.MapHttp.... stuff?

Comment: Yes.. I have that stuff already..

Comment: even I think there is something to do with routing....We dont use Fiddler..tried to install it..but it doesnt get installed due to security..

Comment: For testing, try changing this method to GET and hit it from browser with the url you have given in the post async method

Comment: I just tried..it gives Server Error in '/' Application..HTTP 404 Resource cannot be found error

Comment: Anything wrong in web.config? What is the authentication type? Anonymous?

Comment: i got it resolved.I bahve posted below the answer.Thank you very much  for your help

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved..
Just repalced below function in Routeconfig.cs

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

with below fucntion

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Help", action = "Index" }
        ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "HelpPage" });

and reverted the changes in RegisterArea method to Original.